# Excel formating date field takes inputed 6 digit date and returns universal date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cannot enter a 6 digit date ie '021314'  Feb 13,2014 without the system formatting it into a date in 1958  ie February 14, 1958.  I seem to have set the DATE formula and I do not know how to remove the same from that particular column

Comment: Excel will only accept that value as a number.  Since Excel stores dates as numbers with 1 = 1 Jan 1900, that value, when formatted as a date, will be 21314 days later, or 9 May 1958.  To convert 21314 into 13 Feb 2014, you can either use a VBA solution, or use the Text to Columns wizard selecting MDY as the date type.

Answer (score 2):

With six digits in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2))
```

[image]